# SQL Analysis Services Partition Processing Gradually Slowing Down

Tags: ssas

Over the past week or so we have seen the average SSAS Table/Partition processing times increase to almost 10 times their previous processing times.  AFAIK, nothing has changed with regard to the server hardware (VM) or database configuration over that time.  Here's what I've found so far:

1. The underlying SQL queries do not appear to be the issue, as running those queries independently immediately return results.
2. Looking at the Profile Trace for the processing of a single Partition containing 2700 records, almost all of the time is spent on the 'Commit' phase of the processing.
3. There don't appear to be any deadlocks occurring, at least none captured by an Extended Events query
4. The memory usage on the server is odd.  There is nothing else running on this server aside from SSAS which is hosting 4 databases, and the memory usage never gets above 50%, and  Analysis Services rarely uses more than 5GB out of 31GB available.  The server has all of the default memory options configured.  CPU usage is similar (rarely high).
5. I've created a brand new database on the server with a single table with the same result.
6. There is no antivirus running on the database folders
7. No windows/SQL error log entries that stand out

What else could be going on here?  Anything else I should try?

EDIT: One other thing I forgot to mention, processing a previously unprocessed table/partition or one which has not had it's relationships calculated (e.g. after a process 'Data'), seems to run fast.  It's only when the table/partition is loading new data which needs to be recalculated does it take the longest.  However, running a process 'Recalc' by itself also runs fast.